# Defining a function

Tags: javascript, function, internet-explorer

At the moment I have the below code on a website

```
*global escape: true */
var twitterHandle = "Handle";
function tweetCurrentPage() {
    return window.open("https://twitter.com/share?url="+escape(window.location.href) + "&text=" + document.title + " via @" + twitterHandle, "", "menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=300,width=600"), !1;
}
```

Internet Explorer F12 Debugger at the moment throws up the following error.

The value of the property 'tweetCurrentPage' is null or undefined, not a Function object.

Works fine on Chrome, Safari and Edge but not on IE11 nor Firefox - any help would be appreciated. I have put the code through various online bug checkers and so on. Only error they have come up with is Function is not called... but I call the function in other ways.

Comment: Where/how do you call `tweetCurrentPage()` ? Currently you always return `false` thanks to `, !1;` which is probably not what you want ...

Comment: its called via a link on a button. I have a facebook one which works fine on all browsers called the same way.

Comment: ok I have removed the , !1; and still no luck.

Comment: Why not to return !1 if it is some onclick action and you want to prevent the default action.

Comment: I am confused as the below script works fine on all browsers.                        function fbshareCurrentPage(){window.open("https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u="+escape(window.location.href)+"&t="+document.title,"","menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=300,width=600")}

Comment: *global escape: true */ - doesn't look right....some browser parsers may not compile unopened js comments.... try /* global escape:true;*/

To test type twitterHandle in the dev tool console... is it also undefined in the IE11 console?

Comment: that should read /* global escape:true; */

Comment: Even without the global escape entry it still won't work on ie11 and Firefox